# How to retrieve a JSON object from HttpServletResponse in Spring?

Tags: json, spring, urlconnection, servlets

I have a Spring controller in which I have to read a JSON object from a URLConnection. Currently I am doing this by reading from the connection's input stream line by line. Basically I am reading the text contents of the response line by line.

Is there any JSON api that I could use to populate the JSON object directly from the URLConnection? Anything that integrates with Spring?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770049/spring-json-used-in-spring-mvc) is related?  Essentially, implementing JsonView.

Answer (score 0):

http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.6.0/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/JsonFactory.html#createJsonParser(java.io.InputStream) This could help, as URLConnection can return InputStream. What do you want to integrate with Spring, btw?